# JPA Native Query across multiple tables

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following defined as a native query in a repository (dispenseRepository) :

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT p.*, c.*, s.*, d.* from patient p, consult c ,script s,dispense d "
                + " where p.patient_id=c.patient_id "
                + " and c.consult_id = d.consult_id " 
                + " and c.fk_script_id =s.script_id"
                + " and c.consult_id=?1 ", 
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<Dispense> findInvoiceByConsultId(Long consultId);
```

The Rest Controller has :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/invoice/{consultId}",method = {RequestMethod.GET}) 
    public List<Dispense> invoice(@PathVariable(value="consultId")Long consultId){
       return dispenseRepository.findInvoiceByConsultId(consultId);
    }
```

When I hit the api I only get dispense details:

```
[
{
    "dispenseId": 1,
    "icd10": "J.10",
    "tariffCode": "10010",
    "dispenseItem": "Lenses",
    "price": 400.0
},
{
    "dispenseId": 3,
    "icd10": "J.10",
    "tariffCode": "111000",
    "dispenseItem": "Other",
    "price": 1500.0
},
{
    "dispenseId": 4,
    "icd10": "K.100",
    "tariffCode": "10010",
    "dispenseItem": "Eye Test",
    "price": 550.0
}
```

]

I'd like all the data as per query which will be used for Jasper report

[image: ERD]

```
patient-consult 1-M

consult-script 1-1

consult-dispense 1-M
```

Comment: Since your return type is `List<Dispense>` how you expect to get anything more than a list of `Dispense` objects? Maybe you should try to use a projection or a DTO which will hold all the required info.

Comment: yep that's true - can't expect anything more than dispense details :-) Care to elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: I could try but you have to share more of your code at least the fields of  patient, consult, script, dispense

Comment: I've added the ERD - hope this helps

Comment: Do you have this model in java classes, Entities? It would be easier.

Comment: stackof complaining about too  much code can pick up at https://github.com/hoosainmadhi/optimed.git

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since in your query you return all fields from all tables: `SELECT p.*, c.*, s.*, d.* from patient p, consult c ,script s,dispense d`  creating projections/DTOs for so many objects and fields is very cumbersome. There are 2 ways to proceed. Either specify exactly the fields you want from each table in your query and create a DTO to hold those fields.
e.g.

**Approach 1:**

I chose only one field from each table to make it as example. Please not that you have to convert your query from native to jpa one!

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.demo.ResultDTO(p.patientName, c.reservationNumber, s.addition, d.dispenseItem) from Patient p, Consult c, Script s, Dispense d ...")
List<ResultDTO> findInvoiceByConsultId(Long consultId);
```

and `ResultDTO` class can be:

```
package com.example.demo;

public class ResultDTO {

    private String patientName;
    private String reservationNumber;
    private String addition;
    private String dispenseItem;

    public ResultDTO(String patientName, String reservationNumber, String addition, String dispenseItem) {
        this.patientName = patientName;
        this.reservationNumber = reservationNumber;
        this.addition = addition;
        this.dispenseItem = dispenseItem;
    }

    public String getPatientName() {
        return patientName;
    }

    public void setPatientName(String patientName) {
        this.patientName = patientName;
    }

    public String getReservationNumber() {
        return reservationNumber;
    }

    public void setReservationNumber(String reservationNumber) {
        this.reservationNumber = reservationNumber;
    }

    public String getAddition() {
        return addition;
    }

    public void setAddition(String addition) {
        this.addition = addition;
    }

    public String getDispenseItem() {
        return dispenseItem;
    }

    public void setDispenseItem(String dispenseItem) {
        this.dispenseItem = dispenseItem;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Approach 1 won't work with a `nativeQuery`, you have to convert it to jpa one so unless you convert your query to jpql, **the above code wont work.**

**OR** the much easier but bulkier, keep the query as is and place the result on a `List` of `Map`s.

**Approach 2:**

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT p.*, c.*, s.*, d.* from patient p, consult c ,script s,dispense d "
                + " where p.patient_id=c.patient_id "
                + " and c.consult_id = d.consult_id " 
                + " and c.fk_script_id =s.script_id"
                + " and c.consult_id=?1 ", 
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<Map<String, Object>>  findInvoiceByConsultId(Long consultId);
```

Comment: I went with approach 1. However now I am stuck with the JPQL query. Not sure how to do a join as the  tables are  mapped 1toM unidirectional.

Comment: nevermind - I figured  out  the JPQL