# Spring Data JPA load lazy associations using native query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am querying an entity by using a Postgres specific JSON operator (like `@>`). To achieve that, the query needs to be decorated with `@Query(nativeQuery = true)`. My plan is to fetch the abovementioned entity along with some of its lazy associations. If I were using JPQL I'd simply JOIN FETCH the entity associations, but in this case I can't.

Please share some suggestions.. thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use @EntityGraph with the native query?

Comment: Since you are doing a native query, you just use native postgres SQL. So you can just do `join .... on` in native SQL, right? You just have to create a DTO for the query results, like in the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401207/jpa-native-query-across-multiple-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain Spring Data, you are out of luck because it is simply so limited. You have to use Hibernate APIs to achieve what you want with a native query. There you can specify for a query that you want to materialize some columns for the association of an entity e.g.

```java
List<Entity1> list = session.createNativeQuery("select {t1.*}, {t2.*} from tbl1 t1 join tbl2 t2 ...", Entity1.class)
    .addEntity("t1", Entity1.class)
    .addJoin("t2", "t1", "associationName")
    .getResultList();
```

Alternatively, you can introduce a custom `SQLFunction` to model this PostgreSQL operator and still continue to use JPQL/HQL. See a similar answer for supporting array functions in PostgreSQL: [HQL - Check if an Array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192574/hql-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value/67196916#67196916)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does that mean I will have to write my own result transformer to turn the Object[][] tuples into a custom DTO?

Comment: Not sure how you get the idea that this has anything to do with result transformation. My native query example is pretty clear with the types, and there is no transformation. If you use the `SQLFunction` approach, you are in JPA-land, so you can select your entities are usual.